# Rspec, test Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, rspec2

I've developed a gem which is to use inside a model by adding `acts_as_gmappable` and it's possible to pass options in the declaration.

Now that I want to write tests with Rspec, I'm stuck for all model related functions:

- check if geocoding was properly done
- check I create a proper json from all database entries
- etc ...

I know how to do these inside a Rails app but definitly not for a gem. Any track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this by reading the excellent book of Jose Valim:

http://plataformatec.com.br/crafting-rails-applications/

He describes how he tests his gem using his engine builder:

https://github.com/josevalim/enginex